# How to execute mysql script file in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have almost 100MB of example.sql file. (Actually data export file from another database)

I want to give user the ability to run this file through some interface in my application.
Can you please guide me how can i do that? Should i treat it as simple text file? Either there is any quick way???

In other words, I want to add same functionality as we have in phpMyAdmin, The import functionality.

If you can refer me some class on PHPclass.org that will be great.

Comment: let user upload that file and push it in `mysqldump` or something like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function import_file($filename){
    if ($file = file_get_contents($filename)){
        foreach(explode(";", $file) as $query){
            $query = trim($query);
            if (!empty($query) && $query != ";") {
                mysql_query($query);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

can be called with

```
import_file("files/files.sql");
```

<sub>However, this function will not work properly if file includes semicolon `;` somewhere else than at the end of the query</sub>

Comment: I am just trying, seems like best option. Will be back to select it as accepted answer :)

Comment: This'll blow up hideously if any of the actual data contains a `;`. But for quick 'n dirty, it's "good enough"

Comment: @MarcB: Wow, didn't even think about this situation. In that case there would be a lot of things to be considered.

Comment: I'm kind of lame in this area, but I'm curious why you can't just run `mysql_query($file)` without exploding the string into separate queries. Can't `mysql_query` handle multiple queries in one string?

Comment: You can try to split the file on `";\r\n"`, or something.  In `.sql` files queries should be on separate lines.

Comment: @Herbert: Unfortunately, no it can't.  [mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) to the currently active database

Comment: Wouldn't that break on multi-line statements?  Ie., a MySql dump that includes cruft like `--\n--Definition of table my_table\n--\n` and valid statements like `CREATE TABLE my_table (\nid int\n);\n`

Comment: @Herbert: php's mysql driver disables multiple queries in a single call as a security measure against sql injection attacks.

Comment: @Marc and Rocket: Thanks for the info. I've never had the need to run multiple queries at once, but this is good to know in case it comes up. :-)

Comment: @Rocket: It's fortunately when speaking about SQLi. [This](http://xkcd.com/327/) can't happen with mysql_query()

Comment: @Farray: no. there isn't "or die()" so it will skip these errors

Answer (score 2):

Create a file upload form that allows trusted users to upload the file to your server. Then call the mysql command-line tools from PHP to import the data into your database. Doing it by trying to explode(";", ...) will fail if there are any quoted semicolons within the imported data.